# Technical Interview

Tags: interviewing

I have been invited to take part in a technical phone interview in 6 days time. The technical questions will be based around Computer Networks (CCNA). I am currently in my last year of uni. Although a part of my course surrounds this area, I had a year out of uni last year to complete a year long placement. Therefore, a lot of the information I have gained from my first and second year has been forgotten. I'm a little concerned as I have read up on previous interviews with this employer, although the questions may be basic, they require very thorough answers. But like I have already said, a lot of this basic information has been lost and I feel I am really going to struggle to present the answer to the questions in the interview.

Any tips, or on the approach i should take leading up to the interview?

Comment: If you already suspect that you will struggle with some subjects in the interview, you should study or revise those subjects. What else do you expect us to tell you?  Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Presumably you would somehow get back the 'basic information' that has been 'lost' before, you know, actually starting to work in this field?

Answer (score 7):

**Study.**

If you know or suspect the kinds of questions you'll be asked, you know what to brush up on.

If you've forgotten so much that you can't answer the basics, then keep studying even after you get rejected from *this* interview. That way you can nail the *next* interview.

Comment: I agree with the 2nd part quite a bit here. If you don't get the job don't get all down, use it to learn from. At least then you'll have first hand knowledge of the types of things you're going to get asked and you have a good frame of reference for studying. But seriously, don't stop studying.

Answer (score 1):

Technical interviews for entry level positions seldom are looking for specific technical answers.  Rather, they are probing questions to explore the depth of your knowledge and your thought process of how you get to a solution, not that you actually know the answer to the question.  Frankly, the same is usually true for more experience positions.  I only rarely have been in an interview, either as the applicant or the hiring agent, where a specific technical answer mattered much.  If you claim knowledge of a specific system or technology, then you need to have a fair base knowledge of it, but in general it is about the process in my experience.  In the rare case that is not true, then a week of study is not going to level the playing field with someone having a directly applicable background.  Brush up, but I would not expect a lot more than that.  More important to stay calm and present yourself as someone who can get answers they don/t already have.